# Multi Crop an image in Python with custom parameters

Tags: python, image, image-processing, crop

I’m trying to crop an image into 9 separate images (or tiles) however not 9 equal tiles.

For example,

First row: Height: 20px
Second row: Height: 40px
Third row: Height: 15px

Universal width of tiles: 20px

Then it needs to save all the newly created tiles as separate images (ex: tile 1, 2, 3 etc)

All I’ve found is image split which limits to equal crops. Any ideas?

Comment: I see 9 lines of code, each extracting a slice and saving to a file...

Comment: @MarkSetchell thanks, I actually figured it out. I’ll post the solution when it’s complete

Comment: Cool, well,done! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ExFileName.crop(0,0,0,0)
```

Allows you to crop an image using custom parameters.

i.e `(LeftEdgeX, TopEdgeY, RightEdgeX, BottomEdgeY)`

Using this it's easy to then create a script to set the various bounds for all 9 crops using some lists and a method.

This is the code I used for my project: https://github.com/CTOverton/Custom-Image-Crop-Python